# mongoose and nodejs: count equals undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, count

I'm using nodejs and mongoose to build a little project. i'm using the "count()" function in order to check if I have specific document in my collection.

For some reason when the "_id" property does not exists in the collection the "count" value is "undefined" and not just plain zero.

```
app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {

    var userId = req.params.id;

    User.count({_id: userId}, function (err, count) {
        if (count === undefined) {  
            console.log(count); // in the console count is "undefined"
            res.status(404).sendFile('./ErrorFiles/404.html', {root: __dirname});
        } else {
            console.log(count);
            res.sendFile('./public/index.html', {root: __dirname}, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    res.sendStatus(404);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

in my "if" statement I wrote "count === undefined" just to test that it's working. anyway if the "_id" not in the collection , "count" supposed to be equal to zero, right?

if the "_id" is in the collection then "count === 1" and the function working well. so the issue is only when the "_id" not in the collection.

Love to get some help, thanks.

Comment: There is a difference between presence of property and property value not matching to the query criteria. So I believe when the property is missing the count is undefined and when it it present and not matching the count is zero. Btw why do have `_id` property missing ? Isn't this a key ?

Comment: Can you check for an error in the count callback?

Comment: You don't check if there is an error with `err`. This can explain why `count` is `null`.